# Oracle shifts in work with dates

Tags: oracle

Can you help me with shifts? I need to assign each event what shift it is. 
I want to count how many items machine done in every shift. "ILE" means "HOW MANY ITEMS IN SHIFT WERE DONE"

```
    SELECT lz.EVENT, 
    TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATA,
            CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'HH24:MI') BETWEEN '06:00' AND '13:59' THEN 'First Shift'
                 WHEN TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'HH24:MI') BETWEEN '14:00' AND '21:59' THEN 'Second Shift'
                 WHEN TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'HH24:MI') BETWEEN '22:00' AND '23:59' THEN 'Third Shift'
                 WHEN TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'HH24:MI') BETWEEN '00:00' AND '05:59' THEN 'Third Shift'
                 END AS SHIFT

FROM PLC.LIST lz;
```

But when I check now query and I have third shift of 2017-08-03 and it is wrong because according to sysdate I shound have first shift only.
Any idea?

EDIT:

Whole query

```
SELECT "DATA",
           "ZMIANA",
           "SOV_GAO_1_ILE",
           "SOV_GAD_2_ILE",
           "SOV_GAM_3_ILE"
      FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATA,
                  CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '13:59:59.999999' THEN 1
                       WHEN TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '21:59:59.999999' THEN 2
                       WHEN TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '23:59:59.999999' THEN 3
                       WHEN TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '05:59:59.999999' THEN 3
                        END AS ZMIANA,
                   lz.LINIA,
                   lz.DETAL
          FROM PLC.LISTA_ZDARZEN lz
          GROUP BY lz.DATA_ZATW,
                   lz.LINIA,
                   lz.DETAL) PIVOT (COUNT(DETAL) AS ILE FOR LINIA IN ('SOV_GAO_1' SOV_GAO_1, 'SOV_GAD_2' SOV_GAD_2, 'SOV_GAM_3' SOV_GAM_3));
```

EDIT:

SHIFTS

```
6-14 01.08 first shift
14-22 01.08 second shift
22-00 01.08 third shift
00-6 02.08 third shift

6-14 02.08 first shift
14-22 02.08 second shift
22-00 02.08 third shift
00-6 03.08 third shift

6-14 03.08 first shift
14-22 03.08 second shift
22-00 03.08 third shift
00-6 04.08 third shift
```

HERE ARE DATES:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-01 23:54:56', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 01.08 Third shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-01 23:57:58', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 01.08 Third shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-02 03:54:56', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 01.08 Third shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-02 04:54:56', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 01.08 Third shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-02 06:54:56', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 02.08 First shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-02 07:54:56', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 02.08 First shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-02 10:24:34', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 02.08 First shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-02 14:54:56', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 02.08 Second shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-02 15:54:56', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 02.08 Second shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-02 19:21:10', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 02.08 Second shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-02 22:54:56', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 02.08 Third shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-02 23:55:20', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 02.08 Third shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-02 23:55:56', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 02.08 Third shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 00:02:34', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 02.08 Third shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 00:05:34', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 02.08 Third shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 00:10:38', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 02.08 Third shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:01:24', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 03.08 First shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:01:32', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- 03.08 First shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 17:01:10', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 03.08 Second shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 19:28:45', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- 03.08 Second shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 23:54:56', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 03.08 Third shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 23:55:20', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL -- 03.08 Third shift
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 23:55:56', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM DUAL           -- 03.08 Third shift
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Try `TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS DATA` in order to verify your CASE expression.

Comment: I just want to count how many items machine done in every shift.

Comment: Your data does not match. All your sample data are from `2017-08-03`. How do you expect results for `2017-08-01`, `2017-08-02` and `2017-08-04`? Please provide valid input and expected output for such data.

Comment: Look at the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN 600 AND 1359 THEN 'First Shift'
     WHEN TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN 1400 AND 2159 THEN 'Second Shift'
     WHEN TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN 2200 AND 2359 THEN 'Third Shift'
     WHEN TO_CHAR(lz.DATA_ZATW, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN 0 AND 559 THEN 'Third Shift'
END AS SHIFT
```

or like this:

```
CASE WHEN (lz.DATA_ZATW - TRUNC(lz.DATA_ZATW)) * INTERVAL '1' DAY BETWEEN INTERVAL '6' HOUR AND INTERVAL '13:59:59.999999' HOUR TO SECOND THEN 'First Shift'
CASE WHEN (lz.DATA_ZATW - TRUNC(lz.DATA_ZATW)) * INTERVAL '1' DAY BETWEEN INTERVAL '14' HOUR AND INTERVAL '21:59:59.999999' HOUR TO SECOND THEN 'Second Shift'
...
```

According to your sample data it works:

```
WITH t (DATA_ZATW) AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:03:31', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:03:11', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:03:07', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:02:44', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:02:22', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:02:21', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:01:58', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:01:32', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:01:24', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual)
SELECT DATA_ZATW,
    CASE 
        WHEN TO_CHAR(DATA_ZATW, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN 600 AND 1359 THEN 'First Shift'
        WHEN TO_CHAR(DATA_ZATW, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN 1400 AND 2159 THEN 'Second Shift'
        WHEN TO_CHAR(DATA_ZATW, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN 2200 AND 2359 THEN 'Third Shift'
        WHEN TO_CHAR(DATA_ZATW, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN 0 AND 559 THEN 'Third Shift'
    END AS SHIFT
FROM t;

DATA_ZATW   SHIFT
03.08.2017 09:03:31 First Shift
03.08.2017 09:03:11 First Shift
03.08.2017 09:03:07 First Shift
03.08.2017 09:02:44 First Shift
03.08.2017 09:02:22 First Shift
03.08.2017 09:02:21 First Shift
03.08.2017 09:01:58 First Shift
03.08.2017 09:01:32 First Shift
03.08.2017 09:01:24 First Shift
```

I assume at the end you are looking for something like this:

```
WITH t (DATA_ZATW) AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:03:31', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:03:11', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:03:07', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:02:44', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:02:22', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:02:21', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:01:58', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:01:32', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('2017-08-03 09:01:24', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual)
SELECT TRUNC(DATA_ZATW), SHIFT, COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
SELECT DATA_ZATW,
    CASE 
        WHEN TO_CHAR(DATA_ZATW, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN 600 AND 1359 THEN 'First Shift'
        WHEN TO_CHAR(DATA_ZATW, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN 1400 AND 2159 THEN 'Second Shift'
        WHEN TO_CHAR(DATA_ZATW, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN 2200 AND 2359 THEN 'Third Shift'
        WHEN TO_CHAR(DATA_ZATW, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN 0 AND 559 THEN 'Third Shift'
    END AS SHIFT
FROM t
)
GROUP BY TRUNC(DATA_ZATW), SHIFT;
```

Comment: It doesn't work properly. I have still THIRD SHIFT today:

`2017-08-02 First Shift

2017-08-02 Second Shift

2017-08-02 Third Shift

2017-08-03 First Shift

2017-08-03 Third Shift`

Comment: What are the time values? Providing just the day is quite useless for this query.

Comment: You still do not provide hour and minute values of `lz.DATA_ZATW`

Comment: What do you mean "not provide hour and minute values"?

Comment: Just provide some sample data - dates with time values!

Comment: I added sample data in post. Sorry for table but I can't do table, yet..

Comment: Not working.. 
6-14 01.08 first shift
14-22 01.08 second shift
22-00 01.08 third shift
00-6 02.08 third shift

6-14 02.08 first shift
14-22 02.08 second shift
22-00 02.08 third shift
00-6 03.08 third shift

6-14 03.08 first shift
14-22 03.08 second shift
22-00 03.08 third shift
00-6 04.08 third shift

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only thing You have to do is to substract six hours from `data_zatw` to assign it to previous day.

```
select data_zatw, trunc(data_zatw - interval '6' hour) shift_date,
       case when to_char(data_zatw, 'HH24') >= '06'
             and to_char(data_zatw, 'HH24') <  '14' then 1
            when to_char(data_zatw, 'HH24') >= '14'
             and to_char(data_zatw, 'HH24') <  '22' then 2
            when to_char(data_zatw, 'HH24') >= '22'
              or to_char(data_zatw, 'HH24') <  '06' then 3
       end shift
  from lz
```

Then make your pivot and aggregations and pivot.

Test data:

```
with lz as (
  select to_date(column_value, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') data_zatw 
    from table(
      sys.odcivarchar2list(
        '2017-08-01 23:54:56', '2017-08-01 23:57:58', '2017-08-02 03:54:56', 
        '2017-08-02 04:54:56', '2017-08-02 06:54:56', '2017-08-02 07:54:56', 
        '2017-08-02 10:24:34', '2017-08-02 14:54:56', '2017-08-02 15:54:56', 
        '2017-08-02 19:21:10', '2017-08-02 22:54:56', '2017-08-02 23:55:20', 
        '2017-08-02 23:55:56', '2017-08-03 00:02:34', '2017-08-03 00:05:34', 
        '2017-08-03 00:10:38', '2017-08-03 09:01:24', '2017-08-03 09:01:32', 
        '2017-08-03 17:01:10', '2017-08-03 19:28:45', '2017-08-03 23:54:56', 
        '2017-08-03 23:55:20', '2017-08-03 23:55:56')))
select data_zatw, trunc(data_zatw - interval '6' hour) shift_date,
       case when to_char(data_zatw, 'HH24') >= '06'
             and to_char(data_zatw, 'HH24') <  '14' then 1
            when to_char(data_zatw, 'HH24') >= '14'
             and to_char(data_zatw, 'HH24') <  '22' then 2
            when to_char(data_zatw, 'HH24') >= '22'
              or to_char(data_zatw, 'HH24') <  '06' then 3
       end shift
  from lz
```